# ps: How to get processes with no memory consumption?

Tags: linux, ps

Using `ps aux --sort rss`, I can get a list of processes with ascending order of memory consumption. Is there a way in `ps` to get the list of processes with a certain memory consumption?

i.e. something along the lines "list all processes where rss and vsz equal 0" for example kernel threads.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I know this can be done using filters but as the question mentions, I was wondering whether ps provides such functionality out of the box. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `awk` filter could be used.

We know, from `ps aux` output that `vsz` is column 5 and `rss` is column 6 so we can do

```
ps aux --sort rss | awk '$5 == 0 && $6 == 0'
```

That will only display the fields where both values are zero.

If you also want the header

```
ps aux --sort rss | awk 'NR==1 || ($5 == 0 && $6 == 0)'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, I was looking  for a way to do it without filters. Maybe I should have made that more clear in the question.

Comment: It can't be done inside `ps`.  That also goes against the Unix philosophy; why add filters to every single command when we can post-process output?